# How to group pandas dataframe rows based on two columns to find the count for each day?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

Here is how my data looks:
                                                DataFrame

```
           TagID                           PlazaEntryTime                      PlazaID
     0   2844106899                     9/29/19 9:31:06 PM                       1420
     1   2844106896                     10/29/19 9:31:06 PM                      1421
     2   2844106896                     9/29/19 9:31:06 PM                       1440
     3   2844106896                     12/29/19 9:31:06 PM                      1422
```

I want to find the count of the number of rows each day for Plaza ID = 1420

I used the following code:

`df['PlazaEntryTime'].groupby([df.PlazaEntryTime.dt.day,df.PlazaId==1420]).agg('count')`

the output of which is the following:

```
 PlazaEntryTime    PlazaId        Count
     9             False            0
                   True             2
     10            False            1
                   True             0
     12            False            1
                   True             0
```

But I do not want the count of false results to be printed, can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df[df['PlazaID']==1420].groupby(df.PlazaEntryTime.dt.day)['TagID'].agg('count')
```